# QML : If condition in delegate?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm designing a spinner list control, which displays 3 items at a time.

Its working fine as required behaviour the only issue am facing is I need the central element appearance little bigger.

The approach which I can think as of now is to have an if condition in the delegate, which on the basis of current index increases the font size.

Is the above approach is possible? Any suggestions to achieve the particular behaviour

Below is the code snippet

```
   SpinnerData {
              id: spinner
              focus: true
              model: 20
              delegate: Text { font.pixelSize: spinner.height/4.5; text: index; height: spinner.height }
                }
```

Comment: Not sure what is `SpinnerData` element, but does it has something like `currentIndex` property? Have you tried something like `font.pixelSize: index === spinner.currentIndex ? 100 : spinner.height/4.5;` ?

Comment: Assuming SpinnerData is a ListView, the ListView.isCurrentItem attached property is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the details of your component but [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/qt-components/blobs/master/src/symbian/extras/Tumbler.qml) you can see implementation of the same control in Qt Quick Components.

[image]